# Vlookup on multiple values in a cell

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, textjoin

I would like to be able to return [cat,dog] as shown in column B.  This is more of a POC, but for the main challenge I am facing, there will be an unknown number of values in cell A1.  I'm not sure if there is a way to do this with a vlookup, or if there is a better way to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Guessing there could be more then one canine species (dog, dog2, ...) and all should be returned:

```
= "["
& JOIN(
    ",",
    QUERY(
      A3:B11,
      "SELECT B
       WHERE A MATCHES '^(?:" & JOIN("|", UNIQUE(SPLIT(A1, "[,]"))) & ")$'
       ORDER BY B",
      0
    )
  )
& "]"
```

We just filter out everything that does not match the regular expression `^feline|canine|...$` with [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) using [`MATCHES`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#where) and join it with commas.

Regular expression is constructed in this (just unique words joined by `|`):

```
'^(?:" & JOIN("|", UNIQUE(SPLIT(A1, "[,]"))) & ")$'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("["&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, 
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FLATTEN(SPLIT(A1, "[,]", 1, 0)), A3:B, 2, 0)))&"]")
```

[image]

Comment: Please @player0 always add some sort of explanation to your answer.